# Factory for objects hierarchy (polymorphic static methods workaround)

Tags: java, design-patterns

Let's consider the following simplified `Resource` hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Resource {
    static public boolean accepts(String resource);
}

public class AudioResource extends Resource {
    static public boolean accepts(String resource) {
        //Check if we can proceed this resource as audio
        //Some complex logic there ...
    }
}

public class VideoResource extends Resource {
    static public boolean accepts(String resource) {
        //Check if we can proceed this resource as video
        //Another complex logic there
    }
}
```

`Resource` has dozens subclasses and number grows. Each sub-resource:

- has some logic to determine if it accepts resource or not. E.g. it may parse resource URL with regexp or something;
- is not singleton by design;

Now, we want to create a factory which iterates through all available subclasses and creates one which accepts resource (checks it using the `accepts` method).

Something like this (let's suppose for a moment that Java has static methods polymorphism):

```
public class ResourceFactory {

    private static List<Class<Resource>> registry;
    {
        //Populate registry once on start
    }


    public static Resource createResource(String resource) {
        for (Class<Resource> clazz : registry) {
            if (clazz.accepts(resource)) 
                return clazz.createInstance(resource);
        }
    }    
}
```

Unfortunately (or not?), Java doesn't support polymorphic static methods. **Considering that, what are the possible ways to design `Resource` and `ResourceFactory`?**

Comment: Other way is to employ reflection.

Comment: How `accepts` can be non-static? In this case we would need to create instance every time we want to check.

Comment: You can create instances at some other place and pass them into caller class code as, say, constructor params.

Comment: Reflection is definitely the way, but we don't have required interface for each `Resource` in this case. It's possible to write `Resource` without accepts at all.

Comment: Essentially, they become Singletons, but by convention and not by Singleton pattern. This is called dependency injection.

Comment: Ok, this is the possible way either. Though I still don't like it. We need some special constructors (or public empty?) for all resources in this case. Resource instance in this case encapsulates factory logic for itself.

Comment: you'll have to add each resource class to the registry manually, unfortunately. there's no easy way to look up all classes that may extend a class (unless you are sure they have been loaded into the classpath). whether you do a DI through configuration or add conventionally into the code. the accept method should definitely be non static so it could be overridden. If all the resources are loaded on startup somehow, you could have each class register itself to the registry

Comment: If you don't like using ctors, you can set Resources in client objects via some setter which can be defined in common interface. Though, this way you'd lose option to declare resource fields `final` in client objects, which would require to declare them `volatile` in case of multi-threaded code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
public interface Resource {
  // some methods
} 

public interface ResourceFactory {
  boolean acceptsResource(String resource);
  Resource createResource(String resource) throws UnsupportedResourceException;
}   

public final MultiResourceFactory implements ResourceFactory{
   private static final ServiceLoader<ResourceFactory > resourceFactoryLoader
       = ServiceLoader.load(ResourceFactory .class);
   private static final MultiResourceFactory INSTANCE;

  private MultiResourceFactory(){
  }

  public static MultiResourceFactory getInstance(){
    if (INSTANCE == null){
        INSTANCE = new MultiResourceFactory();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean acceptsResource(String resource){
      for (ResourceFactory resourceFactory : resourceFactoryLoader) {
         if (resourceFactory.acceptsResource(resource)){
             return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
  }

  @Override
  public Resource createResource(String resource) throws UnsupportedResourceException{
      for (ResourceFactory resourceFactory : resourceFactoryLoader) {
         if (resourceFactory.acceptsResource(resource)){
             return resourceFactory.createResource(resource);
         }
      }
      throw new UnsupportedResourceException(resource);
  }
```

See ServiceLoader for how to register the factories:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html

Note: the code is untested

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, we enforce one factory per `Resource`. I thought about this, and it seemed a bit heavy to me. Though considering that `ServiceLoader`'s documentation describes almost what I need ... probably, this is the best solution for now.

Comment: BTW, do you know some other possible ways to design? Without a lot of additional objects? (I mean one additional `ResourceFactory` per `Resource`).